# Pass data from child popup window to parent window,cross domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I have a widget js file,which would be used in different domains. The widget has a Login button which opens a pop up to a login page to authenicate the user.
If the user is authenicated i want the pop to close(lik window.close) plus the popup to send data back to parent container where a listener would open some kind of message or box which would tell the user that they are logged in.

i have tried using

1)window.postMessage with pop up but somehow 'window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { }' doesn't logs any messages.

so does event.data , I'm not using Iframes

2) JSONP for callbacks but while calling a the referrer, it cannot get a callback since the referrer would have html codes.

3) window.name but i don't want to use window.replace to  get page on the same pop up, the pop up should close and neccesary actions should take place on the parent site.

window.opener, cookies dont work cross domain.

Thanks in Advance.